# imported Eclipse project not linking to ClearCase

Tags: apache-flex, clearcase

I imported a project from ClearCase into Eclipse and it's not associated with ClearCase; meaning no check in/check out. The only thing I get under 'Team' is 'apply patch' or 'share project'.

Other projects I import into Eclipse are automatically linked to ClearCase, but not this one.

I even created a separate workspace for this view and still some projects will be linked and others not. It's not even dependent upon project; it's arbitrary.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Eclipse project to be associated with ClearCase,

- not only your sources need to be in a ClearCase view
- but your `.project` and `.classpath` (Eclipse project definition files) need *also* to be in the same ClearCase view, right beside the sources.

In other word, you cannot create a project (which would by default be in your Eclipse workspace) referencing sources in a ClearCase view: since your workspace is not in any ClearCase vob, it won't work.

But if you create a project with its root directory (where the `.project` and `.classpath` will be created) just above the source directory, within a ClearCase repository (Vob), then you will be able to "connect" it to ClearCase.

Comment: Thank you. I see a .project file in my Eclipse projects and in the CC view now. So I'm all connected. However, I'm not seeing an .classpath file. Is that on that same level as the .project file?

Comment: @fumeng: yes, it should be at the same level than the `.project`. Can you edit your question with the full path ("`C:\...`" or "`M:\...`") of your `.project` file? That way, I will be sure it is in a ClearCase view.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\x000000\workspace\x000000_TEST_11.03.00_rtp_d\TESTPROJ_testworks_src\PresentationTier\TEST\Shell\.project

Comment: @fumeng: if that path is a view (in other word, if "`cleartool lsview -cview`" returns something, then it should work. If not, here is your problem right there. You need to define a project within a view, and then import it in your workspace, not define a project directly in your workspace (which would be completely un-related with Clearcase)

Comment: Yes, that path is a view (the 'rtp_d' is the development stream of the project I'm connecting to) and it is working now. I originally created a view and added the load rules (4 projects). I imported each one into Eclipse.