# ClearCase, there is no Associate with Clearcase in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I just downloaded the plugins for using clearcase in eclipse from and put them in plugins and features folders :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/

but when I restarted eclipse, right-cliked on the project (in project explorer), clicked in Team, there is no Associate with ClearCase.

I have :
Eclipse Platform
Version: 3.3.2

Comment: Please update your question with the version of eclipse used and the version of ClearCase.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the plugin has been loaded by Eclipse: check the `Preferences / Teams`, you should see a `ClearCase` section.
If not, check the error logs of Eclipse to see if there a message explaining why the plugin doesn't load.

If nothings work, you can also try the official [IBM ClearCase Eclipse plugin](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21256383).

Comment: Thanks VonC, I downloaded and added the plugins and features in eclipse, there is another file .eclipseextension that I don't know where it should be put. now from Preferences I can see clearcase added in Team, but when I right click in a project (from project explorer) --> Team, still there is no Associate with Clearcase.

Comment: @user1034127: now that would be because your `.project` and `.classpath` Eclipse file are not in a ClearCase view. See for examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432945/imported-eclipse-project-not-linking-to-clearcase/4433604#4433604, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393758/clearcase-plugin-for-eclipse-usage/3393857#3393857

Comment: Thanks VonC, I went to that link, I did not understand anything, I just started this job this week, they told me ClearCase is installed in my machine, I checked out the project from CVS to eclipse, but never touched Clearcase in this machine or any time before.

Comment: @user1034127: the fact that ClearCase is installed isn't the all story. You need a snapshot view (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378) in order to manage file history. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393758/clearcase-plugin-for-eclipse-usage/3393857#3393857 illustrates that the Eclipse files should be part of the ClearCase snapshot view in order for the plugin to consider that Eclipse project as versionned. For more on ClearCase, see stackoverflow.com/questions/645771